# How to process a request with Rails while not locking browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http

I've built a CRUD app that allows clients to scrape links. When the client clicks a button rails goes to the controller and runs the script (I can see all the activity in terminal), but there is not feedback on the frontend. Also, the user can't visit any other pages on the website while the script is running.

I script can take a long time so I want the client to be able to click a button, be redirected to another page and the process to start. The user can leave the page if he wants.

I would also like some sort of way to send an email to the user after it's completed.

Would my backend be able to run many tasks at once, right?

Answer (score 0):

You need a background worker. The idea is to initiate the work when the user "Clicks a button", then let background worker perform the hard work while the user can continue browsing.

At the end the user is notified (email or other means) and the job result is accessible.

Off course several workers can work at the same time.

Have a look at [sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq), [resque](https://github.com/resque/resque) or [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job)

Comment: Thanks, any one more beginner friendly than the others?

Comment: Not really, they are all very easy to use, but quite complex to understand. Take your time and read their documentations, it's well documented. I personally have a preference for sidekiq.

Comment: Perhaps this can help https://ryanboland.com/blog/writing-your-first-background-worker/

Answer (score 0):

You can try EventMachine, if you are using supporting server(Thin, for example)

```
EM.next_tick{ p "hello, it's next tick!"}
```

Will be printed asyncronously